# MongoDB query work but not with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to query a collection with Mongoose, there is the collection sample output with a simple `db.course.find()` query

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("581c9408fc01b15cb21043e4"),
  "calendar_id" : DBRef("calendar", ObjectId("581c5972fd1c59295c34f1b8"), "ecampus"),
  "date" : 1478473200000,
  "title" : "Conception et planification BI",
  "teacher" : "fiolet gilles",
  "start_at" : "08:30",
  "end_at" : "12:30"
}
```

I have a MongoDB query that work well

```
db.course.find({'calendar_id.$id': ObjectId("581c5972fd1c59295c34f1b8")}).sort({date: 1})
```

I am trying to do the same query with Mongoose, in my NodeJS app
I made this query but this one return an empty array because the `ObjectId` is not working well.

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId;
let id = new ObjectId(session.calendar_id);

Course.find({'calendar_id.$id': id}).sort({date: 1}).exec(function (err, courses) {
    console.log(err, courses);
    createJsonBody(courses);
});
```

`Course` is from my model file and is like this

```
const Course = mongoose.model('course', {
    calendar_id: Schema.ObjectId,
    date: Number,
    title: String,
    teacher: String,
    start_at: String,
    end_at: String
});
```

How can I make this Mongoose query to work ? The model is maybe not properly formed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Course.find({'calendar_id': id})` instead of `Course.find({'calendar_id.$id': id})`.

For mongoose $id does not exist.

Comment: Thanks this is the perfect answer !

Comment: Also, you do not need to cast the id to `ObjectId` first, Mongoose does that for you implicitly behind the scenes.